# Can I return two results at a time from one action method in mvc?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

Say I have a controller action intended to return an excel file, but at the same time I need to throw a view also from the same method. ie. I need to return excel also and come back to UI as an acknowledgement that the excel is exported or something

```
 public ActionResult ExportReports(string pickProg, string stateKey, string key, string nextUrl, string pageMode, string prntopt)
        {
            ExcelExportCriteria excelExportCriteria = new ExcelExportCriteria()
            {
                PickProg = pickProg,
                StateKey = stateKey,
                Key = key,
                nexturl = nextUrl,
                PageMode = pageMode,
                prntopt = prntopt
            };
            ExcelExportModel exportModel = Sagitta.Domain.Model.AMSTransfer.ExcelExport.ExportReports(excelExportCriteria);

                if (exportModel.HasQuery == false)
                {
//Below Returns File, I want result on view as well with this
                   return ExportFileContent(exportModel.OutputResults.OutputXML, exportModel.OutputResults.DataFile);
                    //return Json(exportModel, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

                }
                else
                {
                    return new HttpStatusCodeResult((int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
                }
            }
```

The other this to note is: I want it in pure javascript way if scripting is also needed as the request is originating from .asp page and vbscript and javascript are being used.

Comment: Return a view (marked with "downloading") then use AJAX call when the page finished loading so that when the AJAX request reach `success` part, it executes an `ActionResult` that returns `FileResult` containing Excel file.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I return two results at a time from one action method in mvc?

No. But you can return one `ActionResult` with multiple values in a (view) model.

Because any one HTTP request can only have a single response.

I suggest you return the status view, and have they status view initiate the download of the Excel file.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to redirect to a "success" page, that when it loads, via AJAX you request the Excel file (which also requires a kind of endpoint to download this file).

Answer (score 1):

Try with 2 separate action methods. The first one return html to the client, the second on return excel file. Browser will call the the first one first, the second one will be called by javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can only return one `response`  from one HTTP Request. So you can put `view` and `download url` inside that `response` and handle both using `ajax`. Making 2nd call after the success of first call gives transaction/consistency problems. I handled similar scenario as shown below.

I converted `view` into html in the MVC action and returned it along with `download url` property.

```
public string RenderRazorViewToString(string viewName, object model)
        {
            ViewData.Model = model;
            using (var sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext,
                                                                         viewName);
                var viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View,
                                             ViewData, TempData, sw);
                viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
                viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(ControllerContext, viewResult.View);
                return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
            }
        }
```

and in the `MVC Action` i returned following :

```
 return Json(new { downloadUrl= "url", htmlView= RenderRazorViewToString("_View", Model) });
```

The above code returns required data to Ajax callback.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Reports/ExportMyData', 
    data: '{ }',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (returnValue) {
        window.location = '/Reports/Download?file=' + returnValue.downloadUrl;
       $('#uiControl').html(returnValue.htmlView);
    }
});
```

The above ajax call downloads a file and appends `html` to `UI control`. I hope it solves your problem.

This solution is scalable, you can pass any number of parameters or views to ajax call back and you can update multiple elements in UI at a time.